# Find all attributes of object of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I've been at this literally all day, searching for answers and I feel like I am looking in the wrong place.  I am a .NET developer so my mentality around objects is that they usually have a key and a value.  In Visual Studio I can inspect the object and see the keys and the type of values.

How do I do this in JavaScript?

Chrome developer tools doesn't seem to help me.  I just want to be able to "inspect" javascript arrays and objects.  Anyone know a tool or something that can assist me in doing this easy?  Visual studio lets me live debug and inspect each variable/array/object very easily by hovering over it, I would love something like this for Javascript.

I've tried getOwnPropertyNames(array) and I get a bunch of numbers.

Here is my code:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://rsshub.app/instagram/user/jasminealkouri/", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        var doc = x.responseXML;
        var titles = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0].getElementsByTagName("title");

        var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(titles);
        document.getElementById("mainP").innerHTML = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(titles);
    }
}
x.send(null);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am fairly new to javascript but know many other languages so perhaps that is clouding my understanding.

Comment: which object is it you're trying to inspect? If you just `console.log` it at the appropriate point in your script, you will be able to inspect it in the browser console, which appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using lodash from https://lodash.com, you should import it like:

```
 import _ from 'lodash'
```

after you install it and then it lets you get the attributes(keys) of your objects in a very nice way, if your titles is an array you should write sth like:

```
 titles.map((title)=>{
     document.getElementById("mainP").innerHTML = _.keys(title).join(" ")
 })
```

Comment: I would like to use vanilla javascript.